# Unicode encoding doesn't work, after enabling UTF-8

Tags: javascript, php, html, cakephp

I've been trying to make Unicode encoding work on my website, every time I post this symbol "" the result after submit is "?".

I am using this to enable UTF, and I am using cakephp framework.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Update: It only doesn't work on dynamic element posted via Javascript.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't *save* the file as a UTF-8 file.

Comment: In notepad ++ all my  files have "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM" selected under Menu>Encode

Comment: You said it's posted via JS, but you tag PHP? And emojies are encoded via `utf8mb4` wherever that can be set. Everything needs to be Utf8 though

Comment: Yes post is dynamically created element via JS on submit.

Comment: It works file on element which are loaded on page load

Comment: Forgot about my powers to immediately close cakephp questions... however, the "**UTF-8 output with CakePHP**" question should have the fix, using that meta tag usually isn't enough, especially when you are using AJAX to load further elements, where the layout with that tag is not going to be involved. If by chance you are experiencing a different problem, then please add some more info so that people can reproduce the issue.